# c# Extension method with restriction on MyClass convertation Error

Tags: c#, type-conversion, extension-methods

I have got an extension method with restriction on MyClass. What i try to do:

```
public static void GetXmlDocValues<T>(this List<T> collection, XmlDocument xmlDoc) where T : MyClass
{
     collection.Clear();
     foreach (XmlNode item in xmlDoc.ChildNodes)
     {
         ((List<MyClass>)collection).Add(new MyClass(item));
     }

}
```

Then Ive got error:

> Cannot convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProgram.MyClass>`'.
>   Here:`((List<MyClass>)collection)`

Is it possible to do that stuff? Or it makes an error in any case.

Comment: A `Get` method that returns `void`!!! And modifies its object!!! And deletes!!! How about naming it `Reload`? ("From XML" would be implied by the parameter type.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you really want your method to look like this:

```
public static void GetXmlDocValues(this List<MyClass> collection, XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    collection.Clear();
    foreach (XmlNode item in xmlDoc.ChildNodes)
    {
        collection.Add(new MyClass(item));
    }
}
```

There is no need for a generic method if you only want to work with `MyClass`.

Comment: Yes, in fact.
And why we need 'Where' restriction? Only for overriding?

Comment: @Novikov: `where` comes from the use of generics. No generics, no need for `where`.